# Find VM with exact name in get-vm incase of multiple entries

Tags: powershell

I am having code where I am searching VM details using `Get-VM -Name $VM_Name`.

It is not giving any output in below case where I have 2 entries for same VM name like below

```
001_MBM1P
001_MBM1P_Clone_Prj_Win
```

was trying something like blow but getting error

```
get-vm $VM_Name | where {($_.Name -match $VM_Name) -and ($VM_Name  -notcontains 'Clone*')}
```

```
get-vm : 1/10/2022 11:36:52 AM  Get-VM      VM with name '001_MBM1P' was not found using the specified filter(s).
```

Please let me know how can I filter the search which will work in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-contains` and `-notcontains` operators work on arrays only, they are not string operations.

You may use the efficient [`String::Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0#system-string-contains(system-string)) method:

```
get-vm | where {($_.Name -match $VM_Name) -and (-not $_.Name.Contains('Clone'))}
```

Alternatively use the [`-notlike`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-like-and--notlike) operator:

```
get-vm | where {($_.Name -match $VM_Name) -and ($_.Name -notlike '*Clone*')}
```

Note that `Contains()` is case-sensitive whereas `-like` and `-notlike` are not. [This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444798/7571258) shows some ways for case-insensitive "contains" operation using `String` methods.

Comment: Thanks for your response. wanted to know  one thing. for few VM's I am able to get the data using this. but for few I am getting error which I mentioned in my post. Do you know what can be the reason? any access/restrictions?

Comment: @EmptyCoder I have edited my answer to remove `$VM_Name` argument from `get-vm` call. This way it returns all VMs without complaining about VM name not found and we filter the result afterwards. Also you have to check `$_.Name` in the "contains" condition as well.